# Confused about Chess Tournament Solution

Tags: probability

The question is:

A chess tournament has $2^n$ players with skills $1>2>...>2^n$. It is organized as the knockout tournament, so that after each round, only the winner proceeds to the next round. Except for the final, opponents in each round are drawn at random. Let's also assume that when two players meet in the game, the player with better skills always wins. What is the probability that players one and two will meet in the final?

I read this post - [Cannot Make Sense of Chess Tournament Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492258/cannot-make-sense-of-chess-tournament-solution) - and I completely agree with the solution **assuming the bracket is fixed, but I don't get how the solution holds if the bracket isn't fixed**

Specifically, I am confused about "OK, but the bracket isn't fixed: the matches are only determined at the start of each round. Doesn't that make a difference? Well, no. Once all the matches have been played, we can reconstruct a bracket from that: it is as if we had a bracket the whole time, but just didn't know what it was. And so, once again, the probability of $2$ and $1$ not meeting is the probability of $1$ and $2$ being in different halves of this 'unknown' bracket, and therefore still is

$$\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}\text{."}$$

Here is why: the above solution assumes that each player will stay on their "side" of the bracket, but the randomized nature of each round doesn't guarantee that. Even if this "unknown" bracket crystalizes at the end of the tournament, it doesn't satisfy the property necessary for the solution: that is, player 1 and player 2 are on opposite sides of the tournament at each round.

Can someone explain and clear my confusion?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to clear your confusion.

The most straightforward one is to understand that with random pairings in each round there are never any halves or sides of the bracket. They exist only when the bracket is determined before the tournament or reconstructed from the results.

If you do insist that there are really (invisible) halves at each round then the randomness means that the top two players might be in the same half at one round and (if they don't happen to play each other in that round) they might be in opposite halves the next time and couldn't play each other. The probabilities of that switching back and forth would come out to the same conclusion you get from a fixed bracket at the start.

Comment: I don't understand all the talk about randomness. True there are no halves only pairings of 2 players to begin with, but since all we care about is the last round having knowledge of the pairings is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @OlderAmateur The randomness is in the first paragraph of the question.

Comment: I mean it is obvious that the randomness is irrelevant and we can simply calculate odds of being in the same bracket. Not sure if this is what you intended with your answer.

Comment: The point of the question is to understand why random pairing in each round (so _there are no brackets_) gives the same probability of the two best players meeting in the final as if there had been a bracket from the start.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathtt{Revised\; Answer}$

Consider, as an example, a $16(=2^4)$ player tournament.

If there is just one draw at start,

P(#$1$ and #$2$ meet in finals) $=\frac8{15}= \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$

If, on the other hand, there is a fresh draw after each round, player #$2$ only needs to be placed to clear **that** round, and in each round, there is only one position at which #$2$ may lose.

Thus P(#$1$ and #$2$) meet in the final)

$$ = \frac{14}{15}\frac67\frac23 = \frac8{15} = \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$$

Comment: I disagree: in the first round, Player #2 can be in either half as long as they are not paired directly against Player #1.

Comment: To clear the first round, player 2 must meet someone other than player 1. Since the pairings are random in that round the probability that player 2 advances is $1-1/(2^n -1)$. There are no "halves" for each of the players to be part of one of.

Comment: I don't claim surviving the first round is sufficient. It's certainly necessary. With _random pairing_ the probability that player 2 clears a first round of 16 is $14/15$, not $8/15$ as you say.

Comment: You are correct ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: This is right now. It's essentially the same answer as one to the question the OP links to.

Answer (score 0):

Ethan Bolker's explanation is probably the best way to think about this problem, but if you want to doubly convince yourself the result is true, you can observe that if the brackets are not fixed, and are instead set each round, then on the $k$th round player $2$ has probability $$\frac{2^{n-k+1}-2}{2^{n-k+1}-1}=:\frac{a_k}{b_k}$$  of NOT facing player $1$.

Note that $a_{k}=2b_{k+1}$, so multiplying these probabilities out and canceling as appropriate we have $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{a_k}{b_k} = \frac{2^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}b_{k+1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k}=\frac{2^{n-1}b_n}{b_1}=\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}.$$